# R ggplot2 : How to use Latex font \mathcal in y-label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data and plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

df = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(400), ncol = 2))
plt = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) + geom_point()
plt
```

Suppose I want to change the label on the y-axis to be `\mathcal{D}` from Latex, how can I do that? I tried using `TeX` from the `latex2exp` library, but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I tried:

```
library(latex2exp)

plt = plt + ylab(TeX("\\mathcal_{D}"))
plt
```

Comment: R graphics provide only a very small subset of the mathematical typesetting capabilities of TeX. If you want something fancier, you may have to resort to tikzDevice

Comment: The `extrafont` package will let you use a similar font (such as Lucida Calligraphy), but you can't programmatically mix fonts within an expression on the axis. If it's absolutely needed, you can `ggsave` as PDF and edit in Inkscape.

Comment: If you look at the [implementation (line 77)](https://github.com/stefano-meschiari/latex2exp/blob/master/R/latex2exp.R) in `latex2exp` you can see it for the most part maps the TeX symbols onto R symbols one-by-one.  Unfortunately, adding LaTeX features is not as easy as adding a `\usepackage` call. Adding the upper-case alphabet from `mathcal` would entail something like this map, or a nice function, to provide the desired characters.  If everything else about `latex2exp` is fine you have the option of extending that package to add this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The following trick is not an elegant and flexible solution to the problem, but it can be useful in some cases. In addition, I tested it only under my Windows 7 PC.
 Hope it can help you.

(1) Download the calligraphic Parisienne font [here](https://fonts2u.com/parisienne.font).
(2) Install the font (right click -> "Install")
(3) Run the following R code:

```
library(ggplot2)

windowsFonts(
  CAL=windowsFont("Parisienne")
)

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(400), ncol = 2))
plt <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) + geom_point() +
       ylab("D") +
       theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family = "CAL", size=20,
                                         color="red", face="bold"))
plt
```

[image]